# How can a Brazilian open a Windows Azure Account on his behalf?

Tags: azure, internationalization, crm

(Sorry, I've seen a [similar question closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329155/sign-up-to-windows-azure-as-an-individual-without-a-vat-id), but since Azure points out to Stack Overflow, I'm willing to risk my Karma)

Excuse me, I've looked into Azure, but being Brazilian, I was required an CNPJ (CNPJ its basically an ID for Tax Purposes as a Company)

I'm not a Company, I just want to try. Are there any options besides setting up a company to be able to create an account on Azure even as a Brazilian?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the functioning of a third-party web site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done!
They changed the form and put CNPJ as an optional field.
Now is possible to assign a new trial subscription without CNPJ.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently there was some change in the form where the field CNPJ became mandatory, not giving the option to register as an individual.

I've reported it to the Windows Azure team of Brazil and Corp and soon we will have an answer to solve this issue.